# Typescript and Swagger Codegen. What to include where?

Tags: typescript, swagger, swagger-codegen, api-eveonline

So I've generated some swagger models and api services from the swagger file located at https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/swagger.json which gives me a file structure similar to:

[image: Generated File Structure]

I've included the following files:

**app.module.ts**

```
// Eve ESI Swagger Codegen APIs
import { ApiModule } from '../providers/ESISwagger';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

providers: [
    ...
    ApiModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HTTP, // Ioniic Native HTTP Plugin
    ...
  ]
```

Let's say I have a page "fleet-management.ts". I am trying to import the API to be able to use the Fleets service the codegen generated. I've tried including the service, the API file and such and I cannot for the life of my figure out how to access it and reference it correctly.

Any help with what files to include and a basic example of using one of the generated functions would be great. It's a little more complicated again by the fact the API also has configuration options which I can't figure out either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved. The ApiModule needed to be an import (not a provider) in the app.module.ts such as the below:

```
// Swagger Client Services
import { ApiModule } from '../providers/esi/index';
...
imports: [
    ...
    ApiModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
  ],
...
```